# gci and gci -recurse have different kind of outputs

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a filesystem inventory.

This works, it gives me the ower and ACL of each entry

```
Get-ChildItem \\Server\Share\* |  Select-Object @{n='Path';e={ (Get-Item $_.PSPath).FullName }}, PSIsContainer, @{n='Owner';e={ (Get-Acl $_).Owner}}, @{n='Accesstostring';e={ (Get-Acl $_).Accesstostring}}
```

But using `-Recurse` gives me empty Owner and Accesstostring

```
Get-ChildItem \\Server\Share\ -Recurse |  Select-Object @{n='Path';e={ (Get-Item $_.PSPath).FullName }}, PSIsContainer, @{n='Owner';e={ (Get-Acl $_).Owner}}, @{n='Accesstostring';e={ (Get-Acl $_).Accesstostring}}
```

Why does `gci` is sending something different alon the pipe ?
How can i fix this ?
(I don't want to make an array because that would not fit into memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different because one array contains a list of files, but in recurse it is an array of directory objects and each of the directory object contains a list of files. 
The code below will do what you wanted. Please note that path needs to be in quotes if it contains spaces.

```
Get-ChildItem \\Server\Share\ -Recurse | Select-Object @{n='Path';e={ $_.FullName }}, PSIsContainer, @{n='Owner';e={ (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner}}, @{n='Accesstostring';e={ (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Accesstostring}}
```

Comment: Any idea how could I speed up things by only calling Get-Acl once ?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Edjs-perkums [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45954718/864696), this calls `Get-Acl` once and expands two of its properties in a second `Select-Object` in the pipe. *(Also reformatted into multiple lines for clarity, but it's a single pipeline.)*

```
Get-ChildItem \\Server\Share\ -Recurse `
    | Select-Object @{n='Path';e={ $_.FullName }}, 
                    @{n='ACL';e={ (Get-Acl $_.Fullname) }},
                    PSIsContainer `
    | Select-Object Path, PSIsContainer, 
                    @{n='Owner';e={ $_.ACL.Owner}}, 
                    @{n='Accesstostring';e={ $_.ACL.Accesstostring}}
```